# I am getting this error : "Error 102 : non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected" for this request :

Tags: sql-server, database-design, visual-studio, c

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "delete from MYDB where First name='" + first.Text + "'";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    disp_data();
    MessageBox.Show("Contact deleted successfully");
}
```

Comment: This seems like pretty sketchy logic - you want to delete all contacts with the first name "John"? And do you really want to just paste user input into a query and run it? Please look into strongly typed parameters and SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it by putting First name between brackets:

```
delete from MYDB where [First name]='" + first.Text + "'";
```

> ```
> create table t (id int, [First name] varchar(100));
> insert into t values (1, 'John Doe');
> GO
> delete from t where First name = 'John Doe';
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Msg 4145 Level 15 State 1 Line 1
> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'name'.
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=93235f1b6102e0a349b0083dc56cef76)*

Comment: Nice spot (and the edit really helped see it).

Comment: @AaronBertrand thanks